# Is possible to call a method of a class which is sent by intent in android

Tags: android

Is this possible call message.toString() ?

In the custom view:

```
MessageData message = 
mBinding.getData().prepareMessageForSending(mBinding);
Intent service = new Intent(mOriginalContext, Test.class);
service.putExtra("message", message);
```

In the BroadcastReceiver:

```
MessageData messageData =(MessageData)intent.getParcelableExtra("message");
Log.d("--------------", messageData.getMessageText());
```

Comment: Yes it is possible. If you need more help, please provide a [mcve] and tell us what happens when you run the code.

Answer (score 1):

Any custom class is possible to be sent via intent as long as the class implements [Parceleable](https://www.sitepoint.com/create-qr-code-reader-mobile-website/) interface.

Comment: what about execute it's method?